# EF Core Groupby Get highest value of row

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, ef-core-2.0

I have the following table:

```
| Id | ParentId | Version |
---------------------------
|  1 |    1     |    0    |
|  2 |    1     |    1    |
|  3 |    1     |    2    |
|  4 |    4     |    0    |
|  5 |    4     |    1    |
|  6 |    4     |    2    |
```

I am looking for a query *(pref Linq to EF)* where I can select the highest `Version` per group of `ParentId`s.

I currently have something like this:

```
await _context.Actions.GroupBy(a => a.ParentId)
                      .Select(s => s.Max(a => a.Version))
                      .ToListAsync();
```

The only problem I have is that only the version row is returned but I'd like the whole row to be returned per group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to order by descending and take the first in each group

```
await _context.Actions
              .GroupBy(a => a.ParentId)
              .Select(s => s.OrderByDescending(a => a.Version).First())
              .ToListAsync();
```